# Using a fixed-point iteration method to find an approximation?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration, fixed-points

> Use a fixed-point iteration method to find an approximation to $\sqrt{3}$ that is accurate to within $10^{-4}$?

For this method one is supposed to derive an $g(x)$. Typically $g(x)$ can be derived from $f(x)$ but the problem here is we do not not have an $f(x)$. The book says it got $g(x)=0.5(x+\frac{3}{x})$.  I do not know how the book got this result. My best guess is.

$$x=\sqrt{3} \\ x^2=3 \\ x^2-3=0 \\ f(x)= x^2-3 \\ g(x) = \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: **Hint:** $$x = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(x + \dfrac{3}{x}\right) \implies x^2 = 3 \implies x = \pm~ \sqrt{3}$$ So, $$x = g(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(x + \dfrac{3}{x}\right)$$

Comment: Quick question the stopping criteria is $0.920469\cdot 10^{-4}$ . Based on the tolerance we check the zeros and we do not put it in scientific notation yes?

Comment: $p_4=1.732050810$

Comment: If we wrote, $$p = 1.7320508075688772935274463415058724$$, how many digits of precision would that give us?

Comment: $p=1.7$x$10^{22}$

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: or $.017$x $10^{-2}$

Comment: Whats strange is that the answer is not in scientific notation. The number must be 1 to 10.

Comment: They are likely asking how many iterations it took to get that tolerance using fixed point iteration.

Comment: It took 4. $n=4$. Well that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given $g(x)$ is Newton's method for $f(x)=x^2-3$. You could get a different fixed-point method from the Newton method for $f(x)=x-3/x$ or $f(x)=x^{3/2}-3x^{-1/2}$.